# I am having trouble aligning sentences as paragraphs in css

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
p.ex {}
```

```html
<p class="ex">Security vulnerabilities that put customers at</p>
<p class="ex">risk have affected Asda's website for a couple</p>
<p class="ex">of years,a security expert has revealed</p>
```

I want all of my sentences together to form a paragraph. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why dont you just put it in a single paragraph tag ?

Answer (score 2):

Just put all of the text in a single `<p>` tag. The text will wrap as needed automatically, but you can use `<br>` tags to insert line breaks manually.

If you would like to disable/modify the automatic text wrapping, see the [`white-space`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property.

```css
p { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<p class="ex">
    Security vulnerabilities that put customers at <br>
    risk have affected Asda's website for a couple <br>
    of years, a security expert has revealed.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can't combine all your paragraphs into one as the other answer suggests, you can use the `:last-of-type` and `:not` pseudo-classed to remove the margin on all but the last paragraph like this:

```css
p:not(:last-of-type) {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin:0;
}
p:last-of-type {
  margin-top:0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
p.ex {}
```

```html
<p class="ex">Security vulnerabilities that put customers at</p>
<p class="ex">risk have affected Asda's website for a couple</p>
<p class="ex">of years,a security expert has revealed</p>
<div>foo</div>
```